# Javascript canvas game development, closure or prototype?

Tags: closures, prototype

I planning on building a small javascript-canvas game, on the style of Space Invaders and I've been reading about object-oriented programming.
Since I would like to follow best practices in game development, what would you advise: using closures to ensure capsulation but the trade off would be performance(or so I've read) or use prototypes?

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a bigger canvas project you should use prototypes, but for a small project like space invaders the code shouldn't get too messy and closures would be fine